# How to restrict template arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes.

```
class Item {
};

template <typename ItemType>
class Result {
};
```

I want to implement a template, which should accept Item and Result< Item> as its template arguments(or something like int and Result< int>). If the arguments don't meet the requirements, errors should be reported during the compilation process.

What I've done:

```
template <typename ItemType, typename Result>
class Unknown {
 public:
  Result GetItem() {
    Result result;
    return result;
  }
};
```

My problem is that when other types are passed as arguments, no errors are reported.

```
// OK
Unknown<Item, Result<Item>> unknown;
Result<Item> result = unknown.GetItem();

// OK
Unknown<Item, SomeOtherResultTemplate<Item>> unknown10;
SomeOtherResultTemplate<Item> result = unknown10.GetItem();

// OK
Unknown<int, Result<int>> unknown;

// Errors should be reported.
Unknown<Item, int> unknown1;
Unknown<Item, Result<int>> unknown2;
Unknown<Item, Result<SomeOtherItem>> unknown3;
Unknown<int, Result<double>> unknown4;
```

Comment: why do you think the error should be reported ,its perfectly possible to send any type as arguments for a template , if you want to restrict the arguments you will have to do some type checking yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `Unknown` to:

```
template <typename ItemType>
class Unknown {
 public:
  Result<ItemType> GetItem() {
    Result<ItemType> result;
    return result;
  }
};
```

and change it's usage to:

```
Unknown<Item> unknown;
Result<Item> result = unknown.GetItem();
```

Comment: I like this answer, if you have an implicit dependency, (like that ItemType must equal the type contained in Result<T>) You should make that dependency explicit. i.e. ensure that it is always correct. The easiest way to do this is to make "Unknown" take ItemType as the only template parameter.